# React-native run-android command is not working

Tags: android, react-native

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 855 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...

Comment: we'll need much more info in detail, please provide either screenshot or whole error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run the following command.

```
npm i jetifier
npx jetify
```

If the issue remains and terminal shown no class found execption. Try to change the package name of those classes to android x.